# How to .substr() a integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

As the title says, which function will give me a result similar to what .substr() does, only for integers?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is what isn't working:

```
if ($(#itemname).val() == "Not Listed") {

        var randVal = Math.random() * 10238946;

        var newVal = randVal.toString().substr(0, 4);

        $("#js_itemid").val(randVal);

        $("#js_price").val("199.99");

    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and expected output?

Comment: See update in OP for my example of what I'm using it for. Converting it to a string does not work for some reason...

Comment: And what did you expect to happen?

Comment: what's the error? **note:** your `newVal` is never used, you store `randVal` in the js_itemid

Comment: There was an error unrelated to this issue. :( Too many answers to delete, but thank you all! It is solved.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What about ...

```
var integer = 1234567;
var subStr = integer.toString().substr(0, 1);
```

... ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Given

```
var a = 234;
```

There are several methods to convert a number to a string in order to retrieve the substring:

- string concatenation
- Number.prototype.toString() method
- template strings
- String object

---

### Examples

Included are examples of how the given number, `a`, may be converted/coerced.

#### Empty string concatenation

```
(a+'').substr(1,1);        // "3"
```

#### Number.prototype.toString method

```
a.toString().substr(1,1)   // "3"
```

#### Template strings

```
`${a}`.substr(1,1)         // "3"
```

#### String object

```
String(a).substr(1,1)      // "3"
```

Comment: @xcy7e this is an old post -- please explain.  The intention is to convert an integer to a string and perform a substr on the result.

Comment: You dont convert values to strings by adding an empty string to the value. Therefore you can use a.toString() - This comment is just to prevent other guys using this - because its dirty (& ugly)

Comment: @xcy7e: completely disagree.  `typeof(5)==='number'; typeof(5+'') === 'string'` -- types are converted using empty strings.  I haven't looked into this in ***years*** as this is an old post, but `a.toString()` used to be much slower and when this was posted (4 *years* ago) doing string manipulation was already slow enough in browsers like IE6-8.  The selected answer shows using `toString`, this answer is also valid and should stand, not just for demonstration purposes, but because programmers have something called *preference*.

Comment: @xcy7e feel free to email me.  I think you may have a limited understanding of JavaScript and these comments are not the appropriate place for this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Would converting to a string first be ok?

```
var x = 12345;
var xSub = x.toString().substr(1,3);

alert(xSub);​ // alerts "234"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert it to string first with `toString()`

```
var a = 105;

alert(a.toString().substr(1,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
<script>
var x = '146870';

    function format(num){
        return (num / 100).toFixed(2);
    }

    alert(format(x));
</script>
```