# Targeting the prefix of a parameter in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

So I was curious how to target the first two digits in a parameter to use in a function for example:

function getNumber(27867545){
//Here I would use an if statement that takes the prefix of the parameter (27) and tests it in a function. 
}
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: [integer.toString().substr(0, 2);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to .substr() a integer in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729492/how-to-substr-a-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to string, take 2 characters from the left, and convert back to number:

```js
function getNumber(number) {
  var prefix = parseInt(number.toString().substring(0, 2), 10);

  return prefix;
}

var result = getNumber(27867545);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is to use the length of the number:

```
function getNumber(number) {
  var len = number.toString().length - 2;
  return parseInt(number / Math.pow(10, len), 10);
}
```

Or if the length is constant:

```
function getNumber(number) {
  return parseInt(number / Math.pow(10, 4), 10); // 4 equals constant length 6 - 2 length
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way to go about doing so? If so, thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: There are others ways. You can divide by 10 in a loop until the result is less then 100, and then take the integer, for example. What are you looking for?

Comment: I just realized you can do this


function getNumber(number) {
if ((number[0]==="3") && number[1]==="6" || number[1]==="5"){
console.log("hello");
}


getNumber("356878");


The only problem here is that when you call the function it must be in a string. Is there a way to avoid this? Like use bracket notation in a similar way without having to set the numbers as strings? And do this without having to do a loop or  substring function?

Comment: To use brackets notation you need a string or an array. Do you know the length of the numbers the function will be applied to?

Comment: Yes I do, but suppose the length of the numbers was a part of what you needed to include in your function. Say you needed to create a function that does this all in one (Uses the first two numbers and the length to determine what to log into the console).

Comment: I just feel like there must be a short logical way of obtaining the exact number you need, similar to how (with bracket notation) you can obtain the exact part of a string or an array.

Comment: Maybe that is just my wishful thinking, who knows

Comment: I've added two more options that use the length.

Comment: I have tried it in a function similar to what I described above and it does not work. It works on its own, but when you add an if else statement in the same function it no longer works.

Comment: how do you run the code snippet? I'd like to give you a better visual representation of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: No I mean like how did you put it in the snippet above? Ill just edit the last snippet

Comment: ok can't figure it out so here                                                                                      function get(number){
 var number = [number];
 if(((number[0]===2) && number[1]===4 || number[1]===6) && number.length===15){
  console.log("finally");
 }
 else{
  console.log("this should work");
 }
}

get(265674758686922);

Comment: Insert the number into an array won't help you in getting the digits - number[0] is equally to the original number, not the 1st digit. To do what you proposed you need to turn the number into a string.

Comment: Ok, so toString() is a good way. How can I include that in my function above? (If you look to the code snippet, I have edited my function in because I could not figure out how to insert a code snippet of my own) I'm new to this, I apologize

Comment: `function getNumber(number) { number = number.toString(); ... }`

Comment: function getNumber(number){
number = number.toString();
if(((number[0]===2) && number[1]===4 || number[1]===6) && number.length===15)
{ console.log("finally"); 
}
 else
{ 
console.log("this should work"); 
} 
}
 getNumber(265674758686922);

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumber(number){
number = number.toString();
if(((number[0]===2) && number[1]===4 || number[1]===6) && number.length===15)
{ 
console.log("finally"); 
} 
else
{
 console.log("this should work"); 
}
 }
 getNumber(265674758686922);
```

Why doesnt this work?

```js
function getNumber(number) {
  var prefix = parseInt(number.toString().substring(0, 2), 10);

  return prefix;
}

var result = getNumber(27867545);

console.log(result);
```